# "rewind" tensorflow training step

Tags: tensorflow

I occasionally hit a problem with training in tensorflow and stochastic gradient descent where I load a mini-batch that wreaks havoc on my optimization op, pushing it to Nans. This, of course, throws an error in the training process and forces me to start over. Even if I wrap the optimization op in a try statement, by the time an exception is raised, the damage is done and I need to re-start.

Does anyone have a good way of, essentially, rewinding optimization back to a valid state when it hits an error? I would think you could use checkpoints for this, but the docs on saving/restoring are so spotty that i'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest checkpoints are the way to do it. The key steps for your case are as follows:

First create a saver object after you've defined your graph:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=5, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=1)
```

Next, write out check points intermittently during training:

```
for step in range(max_steps):

    ... some training steps here

    # Save the model every 100 iterations
    if step % 100 == 0:
        saver.save(sess, checkpoint_dir, global_step=step)
```

Finally, when you catch an error, reload the last good checkpoint:

```
# this next command restores the latest checkpoint or explicitly specify the filename if you want to use some other logic
restore_fn = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.restore_dir)
print('Restoring from %s' % restore_fn)
saver.restore(sess, restore_fn)
```

Comment: Awesome -- that's what I thought might work -- this code is helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering a different question:

Which optimizer are you using?

Big jumps, like you can get with simple gradient descent, shouldn't be possible with gradient clipping or an optimizer with a limited step size (like Adam).

Comment: This is a good point, and adam does perform better, but i have to use SGD as a restriction of the project i'm working on.